# Concatenate column values based on type result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
  Declare @name nvarchar(max),@Id int
  SELECT @Id=[EmpType],@name =ISNULL(@name + ',','')+[UserName] FROM [dbo].[TestTable]
  Group by [EmpType]
  SELECT @Id,@name
```

Getting error with this code, How can i get the result employee type wise concatenated usernames

[Expecting Result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnDps.png)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: @RajuBandaram . . . Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code makes no sense at all, given that the `GROUP BY` would return multiple rows, but you are assigning variables to the result set (which implies at most one row would be returned).

Comment: [dbo].TestTable] is incorect, [dbo].[TestTable] is corect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below using `STUFF()` function

```
SELECT [EmpType],  abc = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + [UserName]
              FROM [dbo].TestTable] t1
              WHERE t1.[EmpType] = t2.[EmpType]
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') from [dbo].TestTable] t2
group by [EmpType];
```

Comment: [dbo].TestTable] is incorect

Comment: Dear @fa06 , Its not working. Getting Error like "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Column 'dbo.EmployeeLoginMaster.UserName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"

Comment: @RajuBandaram, I've updated my answer - you can check now